# Custom add to cart button/link in variable single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

In WooCommerce 3.0+, I have created some tabs using js and in each tab contains products from different categories. I have managed to modify add-to-cart link for simple products where ones the **`addtocart`** button is clicked it goes to the next tab without refreshing and the product is being added successfully to the cart.

```
if ( has_term( 'jeans-discount', 'product_cat', $post ) ) {
      echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" data-target="2" href="javascript:void(0); %s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="custom %s">%s</a>',
    esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
    esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
    esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
    esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
    esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
    esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
    $product );
    }
```

However I am not able to modify the **`addtocart`** button for variable products in **`variation-add-to-cart.php`** template file:

```
<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>
```

For simple product the addtocart link shows as `href="javascript:void(0); /wordpress/woo-slider/?add-to-cart=73"`.

Is there a way i can do this for variable products **addtocart** link as well?

Comment: which version of woocommerce you are running?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec It's 3.0.0

Comment: Ok, so I have post an answer for both versions of Woocommerce, but I can't test it for real (as your tab system is something custom). Let me know if it works. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For WooCommerce version 3.0+** you will override `variation-add-to-cart.php` template this way:

```
<?php
/**
 * Single variation cart button
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.0.0
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $product;

?>
<div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button">
    <?php
        /**
         * @since 3.0.0.
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity' );

        woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
            'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
            'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
            'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( $_POST['quantity'] ) : $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(),
        ) );

        /**
         * @since 3.0.0.
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity' );

// Set HERE your targeted product category
if ( has_term( 'jeans-discount', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {

    ?>
    <button type="submit" data-target="2" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" onclick="javascript:void(0);"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>

<?php } else { // Other product categories
?>

    <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>

<?php } ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="0" />
</div>
```

I can't test it for real *(as I don't have a system of tabs enabled)*, but this is successful working on my test server without error problems.

---

**For WooCommerce 2.6.x** you will override `variation-add-to-cart.php` template this way:

```
<?php
/**
 * Single variation cart button
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.5.0
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $product;

// Set HERE your targeted product category
if ( has_term( 'jeans-discount', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {

?>
<div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button">
    <?php if ( ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) : ?>
        <?php woocommerce_quantity_input( array( 'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( $_POST['quantity'] ) : 1 ) ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <button type="submit" data-target="2" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" onclick="javascript:void(0);"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>

<?php } else { // Other product categories
?>

<div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button">
    <?php if ( ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) : ?>
        <?php woocommerce_quantity_input( array( 'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( $_POST['quantity'] ) : 1 ) ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>

<?php } ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo absint( $product->id ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo absint( $product->id ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="0" />
</div>
```